# What does "long read" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Meanwhile, Karen Pence "wouldn't so much as say hello to Trump," Michael Lewis, the author of "Moneyball" and "The Big Short," wrote in a Guardian **long read** based on several interviews with Trump insiders and published Thursday.

I guess "**long read**" just refers to **something that takes long time to read**. But I'm not sure if it's accurate.

I know the word meaning of 'read'. What I am unsure is if the phrase "long read" is a set/idiom, which I am not aware of. That's the reason why I asked. If it just means the sense of its literal meaning, then it's fine. I just want to get it accurately.

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/apos-leave-alone-apos-mike-013120713.html).

Comment: Please remember to demonstrate your initial research efforts. For example, looking up *[read](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/read_2)* in the Macmillan Dictionary gives the meaning *an act of reading something, or a period of time spent reading something*. which seems straightforward. if the dictionary definition is inadequate for any reason, please [edit] your post to indicate why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Read" as a noun refers to something you read, a reading material such as a book, newspaper, article. "A long read" is idiomatic, and so are a couple other noun phrases of "read":

> That book is such a page turner. It is an **interesting read/a good read/a must read**.

As you can easily guess, "an interesting read" is something that is interesting to read; "a good read" is a good book/paper etc.; "a must read" is something recommended to you highly.